# как правильно создать CMake проект без qt в QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

пытаюсь использовать qtCreator как IDE для C++ с использованием CMake
для создания проекта прохожу типичную процедуру: 
проект без qt -> приложение на языке C++ -> в системе сборки указан CMake, в разделе выбора комплектов стоит следущее (если что при установке SDK не выбирал android и IOS):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после создания проекта IDE уведомляет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и оставляет мне пустой проект с одним лишь файлом CMakeLists.txt:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main.cpp в свою очередь остается на диске в папке проекта. При создании новых файлов происходит аналогичное: нет файлов в проекте, но на диске они создаются. В разделе настройки проекта при попытке выбрать в меню настроек любой из доступного путем нажатия "добавить" ничего не происходит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что я делаю не так?

Comment: просто запусти сборку... `cmake` сгенерирует файл проекта CodeBlocks, который creator импортирует и отобразит в своей гуйне все файлы перечисленные в `add_executable`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer как если IDE требует сначала комплекты настроить?

Comment: мм... дык и правда, в «комплектах» `cmake` не указан... он вообще установлен?

Comment: @Fat-Zer установлен. Даже указан, теперь компилирует, но просит указать месторасположение скомпилированной программы. Должен создавать в папке с проектом папки для отладочной версии и релизной как происходит в случае с qt, но тут совершенно этого не делает

Comment: пока ничего криминального больше не вижу — попробуй банально пересоздать проект с нуля... какой каталог сборки указан в настройках проекта?

Comment: @Fat-Zer все, получилось, комплект только один и ничего лишнего нет, все само заработало. Кхм... после переустановки с полной очисткой всех папок с настройками которые деинсталлер qt сам не убирает